# Propagating JDBC Jar file to federated application servers

Tags: websphere, weblogic12c, websphere-8

I am coming from managing Weblogic, wherein if we need to deploy a jdbc jar file we do on Admin server. Then target that jdbc to any managed server, without copying the jdbc jar to each managed server.

I am struggling to do same on IBM Websphere. We have 25+ nodes as federated application servers. What we want is to put jdbc jar file on Deployment Manager node and then setup jdbc connection on application servers using it.

However, this gives error stating that jdbc class not found on these application servers. Unless we copy the jdbc jar file to each application server on which we need to configure that jdbc connection.

Is there a simple solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Unless we copy the jdbc jar file to each application server", you don't need to copy the driver to each server, just to each node, then configure the driver at the node scope.  We always recommend scripting your installations so they're readily reproducible, if you do so, tasks like file copies become trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solutions would be to put your driver jars in folder inside `config` folder on your DMgr profile. This folder is copied to all the nodes during synchronization. Then you could use `Environment Variables` to define 'path variable' to that folder, something like`${USER_ INSTALL_ ROOT}/config/cell/${WAS_CELL_NAME}/jdbcdriver/` and use that in JDBC Driver configuration.

Comment: Thank you. This is amazing and very helpful for any weblogic/tomcat admins working on WAS.